# Is it possible to trigger event by non-continuous function?

Tags: matlab, octave, ode, ode45

Can someone please point me in the right direction with specifying an event for a function that is not continuous? For example, suppose that I have Object1 that moves along the x axis and I also have another Object2 that moves vertically at x=100.

I would like the event function to trigger whenever Object1 passes through x=100 and the distance between the two objects is say 10. The problem with this is that when the event triggers, the distance must jump from d=10 to -1 and I this doesn't work for me because the function is not continuous.

```
function [value, isTerminal, direction] = myEvent(t, z)
distBetweenObj = z(1)-z(2)
if abs(distBetweenObj) < tol && objectsCollider(z(1),z(2))
    value = -1;
    isTerminal = 1; % the event should be triggered at this point
    direction = -1; % but for some reason it doesn't
else
    value = distBetweenObj;
    isTerminal = 0;
    direction = -1;
end
end
```

Anyone has any ideas how I could specify this function?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to solve the problem. Could run the ode solver until the object reaches x=100 and then separately outside the event function could check if the second object is within 10 units away from the first object and then integrate again if anything else needs to be done.